# Select all PrimeFaces Radio Button using Custom Layout in a DataTable with Grouping and HeaderRow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to get a button at the top of each section to fill in the N/A radios for just that section when clicked using JavaScript. I am using PrimeFaces V12 `p:selectOneRadio` with a `custom` layout within a `p:dataTable` that uses `groupBy` on a `p:headerRow`. My JavaScript function seems to be altering the selected stated of the radio but the view doesn't reflect that.  Even when I submit the form to the JSF backing bean, thinking the radios might actually selected but just not visually showing as, alas, the radios are NOT actually selected.

[image]

```
    <p:dataTable id="ynnrCheckListId"
        value="#{cc.attrs.checklistQuestions}" var="qAndA">

        <p:headerRow groupBy="#{qAndA.checklistAttribute.attributeCategory.id}">
            <p:column colspan="8" sortOrder="#{qAndA.checklistAttribute.attributeCategory.headerText}">
            <h:outputText value="#{qAndA.checklistAttribute.attributeCategory.headerText}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column colspan="1">
                <p:button itemLabel="This Section Not Applicable" 
                    onclick="doAll(#{qAndA.checklistAttribute.attributeCategory.id}); return false;">
                </p:button>
            </p:column>
```

...
within the Yes column I define the custom layout selectOneRadio

```
        <p:column headerText="Yes" width="50">
            <p:selectOneRadio id="yesNoNA" value="#{qAndA.toggleValue}" layout="custom" unselectable="true" styleClass="ppp">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="YES" />
                ...
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="NA" itemValue="NA" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>

            <div align="center">
                <p:radioButton id="yes" for="yesNoNA" itemIndex="0" rendered="#{empty qAndA.toggleValue}"
                    disabled="#{not cc.attrs.checklistInstance.checklistEditable}" />
                <h:outputText style="color: #000; font-size: 24px;" styleClass="fa-solid fa-check"
                    rendered="#{qAndA.toggleValue == 'YES'}" />
                <h:outputText value=""
                    rendered="#{qAndA.toggleValue == 'NO_MAJOR' or qAndA.toggleValue == 'NO_MINOR' or qAndA.toggleValue == 'NA' or qAndA.toggleValue == 'RESOLVED_MAJOR' or qAndA.toggleValue == 'RESOLVED_MINOR'}" />
            </div>
        </p:column>
```

...

```
    <p:column headerText="N/A" width="50">
        <div align="center">
            <p:radioButton id="na" widgetVar="na" for="yesNoNA" itemIndex="4" rendered="#{empty qAndA.toggleValue}"
                disabled="#{not cc.attrs.checklistInstance.checklistEditable}"
                styleClass="#{qAndA.checklistAttribute.attributeCategory.id}" />
            <h:outputText style="color: #000; font-size: 24px;" styleClass="fas fa-times" rendered="#{qAndA.toggleValue == 'NA'}" />
        </div>
    </p:column>
```

...

Setting the styleClass for the NA p:radioButton (above) to the section category id was a way to find just the radios in each section.  The section category id got set in Div's classname that wrapped each row of radios.

```
function doAll(divClass)
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(divClass);
    for (const div of divs) {

        $(div).find('input:radio').each(function() {

            console.log($(this).attr('id') );
            console.log("radio value " + $(this).val());
            console.log("is radio checked? " + $(this).prop('checked'));

            $(this).prop('checked', true);

            console.log("Now is radio checked? " + $(this).prop('checked'));
            $(this).trigger('click');
            $(this).trigger('change');

            console.log("");

        });
    }
```

}

```
assignmentForm:accordion:stageGate1:ynnrCheckListId:0:yesNoNA:4_clone
radio value NA
is radio checked? false
Now is radio checked? true

assignmentForm:accordion:stageGate1:ynnrCheckListId:1:yesNoNA:4_clone
radio value NA
is radio checked? false
Now is radio checked? true

assignmentForm:accordion:stageGate1:ynnrCheckListId:2:yesNoNA:4_clone
radio value NA
is radio checked? false
Now is radio checked? true

assignmentForm:accordion:stageGate1:ynnrCheckListId:3:yesNoNA:4_clone
radio value NA
is radio checked? false
Now is radio checked? true
```

When I manually select one of the NA radios and then click the NA all button, I get true for the checked property before programmatically applying the radio property `checked` to true. So I feel I am working on the correct HTML objects.

```
assignmentForm:accordion:stageGate1:ynnrCheckListId:0:yesNoNA:4_clone
radio value NA
is radio checked? true
Now is radio checked? true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a reproducer? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: no. unfortunately my company started blocking our use of GitHub.  I suppose I could generate it at home and then upload from there.   Hoping that someone saw something obvious that I was missing from what I posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8850309/358794    This is giving me some clues.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I've forked the PrimeFaces sample maven project and inserted my test code and then committed to:  https://github.com/jrozycki/primefaces-test     Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when you use 13.0.0-RC2?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same behavior running primefaces-13.0.0-RC2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to programmatic manipulation with PrimeFaces / jQuery UI you need to think like a real end user not as a web scraper. If you right-click the desired radio button in your favorite webbrowser and inspect the element, then you'll see that it's the element with `.ui-radiobutton-box` class which appears in the inspector, not the hidden input element.

[image]

You'll need to trigger the event on exactly that `.ui-radiobutton-box` element because it's the one who has the necessary [JavaScript listener](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/13.0.0-RC2/primefaces/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.selectoneradio.js#L139) attached to it which does all the necessary hidden input and CSS manipulation under the covers. It's about 15 lines of code which you don't at all need to repeat in your custom function.

In other words,

```js
$(div).find('input:radio:first').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).closest(".ui-radiobutton").find(".ui-radiobutton-box").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

did it for me in [your test project](https://github.com/jrozycki/primefaces-test):

[image]

```
 Question : 1a-1  value is NA
 Question : 1a-2  value is NA
 Question : 1a-3  value is NA
 Question : 1a-4  value is NA
```

Comment: Sorry I did not realize I needed to click on the bounty to award it.  I assumed that it would have been awarded to you by accepting your answer.

Comment: No problem. It will be auto-awarded to the accepted answer when bounty expires. It's actually better to let the system auto-award the bounty because bountied questions will rank higher in list by time and hence there's more chance that people will upvote the Q so that you can earn back the rep spent to bounty.